# unable to consume kafka message through spark stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume message from kafka producer through spark streaming program .

Here is my program

```
  val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
      val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local")
      val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

      val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
      val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
     // lines.print()
lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
            rdd.foreach(message=>
      println(message))
    })
```

The above program is running successfully. But I could not see any message get printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your master url using `"local[*]"`

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]")
```

You can also try to call collect() and see if you get messages.

```
lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.collect().foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: I dont want use collect  .Its not efficient Since i will be getting 10 k to 50 k records.

Comment: I tested the loop you have written for print and that is working fine for me. I just wanted you to check using collect() if you get the message. Check your topic name. Did you try using kafka-console-consumer if you can see the messages?

Comment: I can see the message in both kafka consumer and using collect().what you have tested i dont get it?